# Openpyxl - object has no attribute 'load_workbook'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to load an existing workbook using openpyxl.
But when I'm trying to run [this code](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) - I'm getting following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_workbook'
```

`import openpyxl` works fine, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of `openpyxl` are you using?

Comment: That's quite an old version. The API may have changed meanwhile. Do you have the option to upgrade to the latest release (1.5.8)?

Answer (score 13):

The examples are for a later version of `openpyxl`. In 1.1.4 the main `__init__.py` did not provide a shortcut to `load_workbook` in the form of

```
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
```

so you will have to do that instead of:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

what is shown in the example.