# Issue opening existing workbook

Tags: python

When trying to open an existing workbook, with the following code, I get an error:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\PythonScripts\\racing.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(path)
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/PythonScripts/openpyxl.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openpyxl
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/PythonScripts\openpyxl.py", line 3, in <module>
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
ImportError: cannot import name 'load_workbook' from partially initialized module 'openpyxl' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/PythonScripts\openpyxl.py)
```

Comment: do you have a file called `openpyxl` in your Path, which does not belong to the module? I'm pretty sure you do and you should rename it to something else

Answer (score 0):

Do this way.

```
import openpyxl

ref_workbook= openpyxl.load_workbook('myfile.xlsx')

path='c:/files/pythonexcel/myfile.xlsx'

ref_workbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
```

Or try this :

The examples are for a later version of openpyxl. In 1.1.4 the main **init**.py did not provide a shortcut to load_workbook in the form of

```
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
```

so you will have to do that instead of:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

Reference :[Openpyxl - object has no attribute 'load_workbook'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000128/openpyxl-object-has-no-attribute-load-workbook)

Comment: Thanks. But I still get the same error  ImportError: cannot import name 'load_workbook' from partially initialized module 'openpyxl' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: can you reinstall openpyxl ?